# Graphite or Django seems to be missing some templates and I don't know how to supply them

Tags: python, django, graphite, graphite-carbon

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.infoq.com/articles/graphite-intro

Everything works until the end when I execute this line:

`tail -f /opt/graphite/storage/log/webapp/process.log`

I see on the terminal:

`django-admin.py runserver --pythonpath /opt/graphite/webapp --settings graphite.settings 0.0.0.0:8085`

but then I navigate with my browser to `my_ip:8085` where `my_ip` clearly is my otherwise working ip address.

I then get this error in the browser:

`A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.`

And in my terminal I get this error:

```
[19/Apr/2017 03:48:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 153, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 228, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
File "/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/views.py", line 7, in server_error
    template = loader.get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 145, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: In `graphite-web/webapp/graphite/settings.py`, set `DEBUG = True`, It might help you get more exception information.

Comment: I did that, but yet the error remains exactly the same and there's no additional output that I can see.